# Multiplication by a power of 2 using Logical shifts in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, multiplication, bit-shift

Can someone please give me pointers on how I can go about making a code that multiplies using shifts in MIPS assembly? I don't understand how having a number 2^n can help me multiply using an odd multiplicand

---

I currently have this code, I'm trying to make a calculator

```
.text

li  $v0, 4 
la  $a0, ask_1
syscall

li  $v0,5
syscall
move    $s1, $v0


li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, ask_2
syscall

li  $v0,5
syscall
move    $s2, $v0

#sll    $s2, $s2, 3     #$s2 * $s2^3 = result
srl $s2, $s2, 1

li  $v0, 1
la  $a0, ($s2)
syscall


.data

ask_1:  .asciiz     "Enter Multiplier\n"
ask_2:  .asciiz     "Enter Multiplicand\n"
result: .asciiz         "The Answer is:\n"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shifting a number n bits left *multiples the number by 2<sup>n</sup>*. For example `n << 3 = n*2³ = n*8`. The corresponding instruction is

```
SLL $s1, $s2, 3       # $s1 = $s2 * 8   shift left by 3 bit-positions
```

To multiply any number you can split the number into sums of power of 2s. For example:

- `n*10 = n*8 + n*2 = (n << 3) + (n << 1)`

  ```
    SLL $t1, $s2, 1
    SLL $t2, $s2, 3
    ADD $s2, $t1, $t2
  ```

You can also use a subtraction if it's faster

- `n*15 = n*16 - n = (n << 4) - n`

  ```
    SLL $t1, $s2, 4
    SUB $s1, $t1, $s2
  ```

Comment: Thanks, so how do i get the final answer say n = 3

Comment: n = 3 but n multiplied by how much? Anywayt that's a simple math, you can figure it your own

Comment: i know how to do this with iterative addition, whilst using one number as a counter, what am asking is: Does n maybe determine how many shifts you perform ?? and is the a way of breaking the number into powers of two automatically in mips,, SORRY, IM JUST REALLY CONFUSED!

Comment: in my example n is a variable multiplicant multiplied by a constant multiplier. The shift is determined by the multiplier. If you mean n is a multiplier then the shift is determined by 1 bits in n, like [multiply in binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier#Multiplication_basics)

Answer (score 3):

> i dont understand how having a number 2^n can help me multiply using an odd multiplicand

Here are some examples for when one of the factors is constant:

```
// x *= 3
temp = x << 1  // x*2
x = temp + x   // x*2 + x

// x *= 10
temp = x << 1  // x*2
x = temp << 2  // x*8
x = temp + x   // x*2 + x*8

// x *= 15
temp = x << 4  // x*16
x = temp - x   // x*16 - x
```

---

**EDIT:** Since you've now explained that both the multipler and multiplicand are variable (which I don't feel was clear in your original question), I'm updating my answer with an explanation of how to go about doing the multiplication:

The algorithm works like this:

```
result = 0
shift = 0
foreach (bit in multiplicand) {
    if (bit == 1) {
        result += multiplier << shift
    }
    shift += 1
}
```

And a MIPS assembly implementation could look like this:

```
# In: $s1 = multiplier, $s2 = multiplicand
# Out: $t0 = result
move $t0,$zero      # result
mult_loop:
    andi $t2,$s2,1
    beq $t2,$zero,bit_clear
    addu $t0,$t0,$s1  # if (multiplicand & 1) result += multiplier << shift
bit_clear:
    sll $s1,$s1,1     # multiplier <<= 1
    srl $s2,$s2,1     # multiplicand >>= 1
    bne $s2,$zero,mult_loop
```

Note that I use a loop to make things simpler. But you could unroll the loop if you wanted to (i.e. duplicate the loop body)

Comment: i may not use any looping structure, but am allowed to use sub, add e.t.c

Comment: No loops are needed. It can be done with shifts, adds and subs, as I show in my examples.

Comment: :( i really dont understand what this " temp = x << 4  // x*16 " means, please dumb it down for me!

Comment: `<<` is a left shift, i.e. the `sll` instruction in MIPS assembly. `x` means the register holding the original value that you want to multiply, and `temp` means a register (any register) that you use as a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

to multiply a number by 2, you just shift it to the left.
To divide it by to, shift it to the right.

Example : 2 = 10 (binary)
-> 2*2 = 4 -> 4 = 100 (binary) = SLL(2) = SLL(10) (binary)

The MIPS instruction would be : SLL $s1, $s2, 1