# MIPS Assembly Language (Power2)

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am currently looking for the best method for performing an n power2 function. In short, the code in MIPS should calculate 2n. n being a positive number stored in `$a0`. However, as of right now my results are coming one power less.

**My Attempt**

```
main:

    # initialize 
    la  $a0,3       #n counter
    li  $s0,2       #base number
    li  $s1,0       #calculated value

While:  
    beq $a0,$zero,exit      #Checks if n is zero, if yes exit program 
    sllv $s1,$s0,$a0        #Shift left logical by n, this should do the math 2^n

exit:
```

[image: Results from QtSpim]

Comment: Related: [Multiplication by a power of 2 using Logical shifts in MIPS assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18812319)

Answer (score 4):

"Failed" isn't a very informative statement. Anyway, the correct syntax for `beg $a0,$zero,j Exit` is `beq $a0, $zero, exit` but you don't even need that check. You should load `$s0` with `1` not `0` since `2^0` is `1` and `sll $s0, 2, $a0` should be `sllv $s0, $s0, $a0`.

Comment: Fixed the issues and j exit code. It is now running in QtSpim but sadly the results are not being pushed to $s0 as seen in the result image above.

Comment: Make sure you examine the registers at the right point. With the `beq` in place that code doesn't do anything except load `$s0` with `1` and that should work no matter what.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "the right point." What I am missing for my QtSpim is producing no results.

Comment: Okay I am now getting results. However, it is producing 1 more power value of n. For example, when n=3. The results are 16 instead of 8. Please see new question info above.

Comment: Well, that's to be expected since you initialize `$s0` with 2. `x << y` doesn't correspond to `x^y`, it corresponds to `x * (2^y)`, which is why you end up with the results you describe.